# Bash won't change variable value

Tags: bash

I am trying to change the variable `reload` from `0` to `1` as you can see in my code below:

```
for d in /home/*; do
  u="${d##*/}";
  reload=0;
  echo "Checking $u";
  if [ -e /home/$u/info/reload.php ]; then
    echo "FOUND!";
    reload=1;
  fi
done
echo $reload;
if [ $reload = 1 ]; then
  service apache2 reload
fi
```

The problem is that it doesn't get changed, `$reload` remains as `0`, the output is similar to this (apache does not get reloaded):

```
Checking user1
FOUND!
Checking user2
0 #< this should be 1 not 0 :(
```

Why won't my bash variable change??

Comment: `find /home/ -type f -name reload.php | egrep -q '/home/.*/info/reload.php' && service apache2 reload`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're resetting `reload` for each user. If the file is not found for the last user, `reload` will be `0` when you exit the loop.

Suggested fixes (with indentation for readability):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

reload=0
for d in /home/*; do
    u="${d##*/}"
    echo "Checking $u";
    if [ -e /home/$u/info/reload.php ]; then
        echo "FOUND!"
        reload=1
    fi
done
echo $reload
if [ $reload -eq 1 ]; then
    service apache2 reload
fi
```

Comment: Ah, whoopsie :o, thanks for your help :D, will accept this an the answer soon as it lets me..

Comment: You might as well `break` after setting reload=1

Comment: @glennjackman: I considered that as a performance improvement, but it would change the behaviour of listing which home directories contained the script, so omitted this.